# How to write single and double quotes in h:outputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How can I write single and double quotes in the value attribute of `h:outputText`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work in both standard syntax JSPs and XML view technologies:

```
<h:outputText value="quote: &quot; apostrophe: &apos;"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

**for Double quote:**

```
<h:outputText value=" &#34; " />
```

**For Single Quote:**

```
<h:outputText value=" &#39; " />
```

Comment: This will work if the view is XML; these entities aren't interpreted in standard JSP syntax (at least, not in Glassfish).

Comment: just double-checked; `&quot;` and `&apos;` are a formal part of the JSP 2.2 syntax (see the `QuotedChar` part) whereas other entities are not.

Answer (score 3):

Can you escape them with a backslash, like this:

```
<h:outputText value="My text with \'single quotes\' and \"double quotes\"" />
```

**Edited**

As McDowell said, you can't do this with XML syntax files.

Comment: This will work in JSP standard syntax, but would be illegal in JSP XML syntax or Facelets.

Comment: @McDowell Thanks for correcting me. I haven't tried this myself, so I wasn't quite sure.