# Using multiple quotes in JSF file

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.2, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm trying to set up the value and I'have single quotes inside double quotes and inside single quotes I also need single quotes:

value="#{vendor.active == true ? '#{'i18n[home.form.header3.close']}' : '#{i18n['home.form.header3.open']}'}"

I'm doing it this way:

value="#{vendor.active == true ? '#{'i18n[home.form.header3.close']}' : '#{i18n['home.form.header3.open']}'}"

And I'm getting this error:

[image: jsf_error]

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354718/how-to-write-single-and-double-quotes-in-houtputtext

Comment: The question you pose is answered via reading https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+escape+quotes+in+EL+jsf but you have a different problem here. First you should know you are using Expression Language here, EL. Secondly you should know that you cannot 'nest' EL (there is no need to and you would not run into this issue in 'simple cases like this') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183887/nesting-variables-in-el.

Comment: And please don't post errors in images. Not searchable by searchengines (or copy/pasted by us into a searchengine) and `value="#{vendor.active == true ? i18n['home.form.header3.close'] : i18n['home.form.header3.open']}"` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting variables in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183887/nesting-variables-in-el)